# Java Object itself in array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I want so save "Object" inside an array.
I DONT want to save "new Object()" inside an array.

Why?
I have 3 big If Statements where i check if a Instance is instanceof SomeClass, e.g.

```
if (x instanceof String) {
   SomeMethod(x, String);
}
```

I Plan Something like:

```
Class<?>[] classes = {Object, String, SomeOtherClass};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (x instanceof classes [i]) {
       SomeMethod(x, classes [i]);
    }
}
```

However this is working

```
Class<?>[] classes = {Object.class, String.class, SomeOtherClass.class};
```

but then i can't use instanceof any more.

Any Suggestions?

P.S: while searching for this i only found how to save an Instance of a Class inside an array, not the Class itself...

Edit: 
at the Position of SomeMethod i want to use a generic Type based on the Class (`Object`,`String`).
This does not work with `Object.class`, `String.class`.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
if (x.getClass() == classes[i]) {
```

instead of `instanceof` for this.

But please be aware that any code that uses either of these techniques is suspicious from the start and probably needs refactoring. Why do you want to store your objects in such a way that you don't know their type?

Comment: This will not work like the `instanceof` operator if polymorphism is involved.  For example, `Class<?> cls = Numer.class; Object obj = new Integer(0); System.out.println(cls == obj.getClass());` will print `false` although `obj instanceof Number`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i have to create a Generic Class within the if Statement, and Something like `new ArrayList<String>` is Possible, but `ArrayList<String.class>` or `ArrayList<classes[i]>` doesn't work

Comment: @mac.1 Yes, this is downright impossible, I'm afraid, because of *type erasure*: generics lose all their type parameters during the compilation phase. This is another reason for thinking that you need to rework your code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store “`Object`” inside an array because `Object` is not a thing.  The string `Object` is a class name and meaningful to the compiler but nothing you can operate on in your program which (apart from the built-in primitives) can only deal with *instances* of classes, that is *objects*.  `Object.class`, on the other hand, is an object (of type `Class`).

What you are looking for is [`java.lang.Class.isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-).  Then use a list of `Class` objects.